# Exporting data from FileMaker GO on an iPad

Tags: ipad, filemaker

I am trying to export data from all records in a FM database on FM GO on an iPad in an xlsx format. I can export ok apart from layouts which have a tab control layout - these layouts only seem to export the data from the tab viewed rather than all the tabs on the screen. I know I have made this work before so all the fields appear in the "select fields" list but now I can only seem to get the current tab fields to show in that list when exporting. Can anyone help?

Thanks
Penny

Answer (score 0):

On the desktop, when you export records there is a drop-down list with two options: fields on the layout and all fields related to the content. Only fields from the visible tabs will be included in the first option.

In FileMaker Go the behaviour is the same, but you do not have a drop-down and it defaults to the fields placed on the layout. Simple workaround is to place missing fields on the layout and make them non-editable and invisible.

I tested on FM Go 11, but I do not think this functionality changed in later versions. In 12/13 you can try to place the fields to the right of the layout border, not sure if it works.